# Bootstrap Timeline Fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, timeline

I am creating a Bootstrap timeline and it is working fine in mobile or small screen devices. But it has some problems in larger screen devices. Check it out at https://codepen.io/irshad437/pen/rLvxxa. And try resizing your windows to check its functionality. It should work same as in mobile devices.
**Kindly check it on codepen.(On given link)**

Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="timeline">
      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="timeline-inverted">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
          <div class="timeline-heading">
            <h4 class="timeline-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Timeline.css */
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.timeline:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 40px;
    width: 8px;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.timeline > li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
    clear: both;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
    clear: both;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 46%;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 0px;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: -15px;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    right: -14px;
    border-top: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid #fff;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 17px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
    float: right;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
    right: auto;
    left: -15px;
    border-right-width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
    right: auto;
    left: -14px;
    border-right-width: 14px;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

.timeline-badge.primary {
    background-color: #2e6da4 !important;
}

.timeline-badge.success {
    background-color: #3f903f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}

.timeline-badge.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f !important;
}

.timeline-badge.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de !important;
}

.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-body > p + p {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    ul.timeline:before {
        left: 40px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        top: 16px;
        left: 17px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
        right: auto;
        left: -15px;
        border-right-width: 15px;
        border-left-width: 0;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
        right: auto;
        left: -14px;
        border-right-width: 14px;
        border-left-width: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the calculated width for `.timeline-panel` till `767px` resolution. And for other devices the width is `46%`. This is why the timeline-panel is not aligned next to the icon.

## Solution #1

Try giving calculated width for timeline-panel for all devices. So remove calc in `(min-width:767px)` and add it to top declartion.

```
ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 46%; // remove this or can be fallback
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 0px;
    width: calc(100% - 90px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
 }
```

## Solution #2

Remove width for `.timeline-panel` in `(min-width:767px)` and update the top declaration,

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    //remove
     /*ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
      } */ 
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 100px;
}
```

I prefer this approach. here's the code pen for this,
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZrqGO

Thanks!